# Hibernate dont allow to delete child element

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Let's say I have 2 entities like that

```
class Parent {
    String name;
    Child children;
}

class Child {
    String name;
    Parent parent; 
}
```

The thing is that I don't want to allow deleting child from database if it's associated with any Parent -> child in parent can't be null. Is there any way to do it? I could just check it with some forloop everytime i try to delete child from db (like query all parents and check their childId), but it doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Comment: Are you talking about deleting rows or a table?

Comment: One row 'child' from Child table, but i want only to do that if this specific child is not associated with any patent. It is optional for patent to have child, and for child to have parent when i create them as entitites, but if later I add child to parent, i dont want to be Able to delets this child, firstly i would have to delete parent. Also i dont want to use cascading So that deleting parent doesnt cause deleting child

Answer (score 2):

Probably your sample should be:

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(optional=false)
    private Set<Child> children;

    // getter/setter
    ...
}


public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // getter/setter
    ...
}
```

So take a look in this annotation: @OneToMany(optional=false), it is for enforcing NOT NULL constraint.

Here you can find more information: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5674

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not well defined, but i will asume you are using tags like @Entity since you put the Hibernate and jpa tags.

In this case you should use a @OneToMany relationship (Parent -> child) and @ManyToOne in (Child -> Parent). If you do so one of them will store the id(or whatever you use as id column). When you do the addParent method and removeParent (from Child) just don't delete the other and that's it.